# Why cant I use this reference after importing the datetime class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-datetime

I am trying to import timedelta from class datetime without importing everything (import datetime):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Error: Unresolved attribute reference 'timedelta' for class 'datetime'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your import statement

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

You imported two things from the module `datetime`. The `datetime` and `timedelta` classes, which are now injected into the applications global scope. You no longer need to use the `datetime` module name to reference those classes.

You can just call it like.

```
>>>timedelta(seconds=1)
```

If you imported the module as whole (which I realise you don't want to do) then you could use the syntax from your question.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
datetime.timedelta(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
from datetime import timdelta
timedelta(seconds=1)
```